# Print a certain number of characters from the end of the string SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2 I want to get 3 symbols from the end of the string.
How can I do that?
Example:

Input:

```
yyre*dsnj*001*19
asdf*wqer*136002*20
```

Output:

```
001
002
```

Comment: `SUBSTR()` - https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html?pos=2

Comment: seems like you asking for 3 characters somewhat near the end of the string.   Need to better clarify your request and the data.  Also platform and version of Db2 you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

RIGHT function
ALPHA has a value of ABCDEF.

```
SELECT RIGHT(ALPHA,3)
     FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

returns DEF,

https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000844.html?pos=2

Comment: OP is not actually after the last 3 chars as the title suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the characters between 6 and 4 from the end of the string.  If so:

```
select strleft(strright(col, 6), 3)
```